# How to make JPA @query work with projection that has another projection in it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to get projections works on `@query` in JPA with joined columns as an another project as well.

Say, I have 2 entities: course and student and student can have many courses and the foreign key is on the course table:

`student(id, name, email, age, grade, uuid)`

`course(id, name, uuid, student_id)`

And I have projections like these:

```java
public interface CourseProjection {
  UUID getUuid();
}
```

And,

```java
public interface StudentProjection {
  String getName();
  String getEmail();
  Set<CourseProjection> getCourses();
}
```

In the entity:

```java
public class Student {
    // other code
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private Set<Course> courses = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

I need to do `LIKE` search on multiple columns including course uuid.
I also need I also want pagination.
So, in the repository, I want to do something like:

```java
@Repository
interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, UUID> {
  @Query(
     value = "SELECT * FROM student s LEFT JOIN courses c ON s.id = 
     c.student_id WHERE s.name LIKE %str% OR c.student_id::text LIKE %str%",
     nativeQuery = true
  )
  Page<StudentProjection> findAllByKeyword(String keyword, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I want the result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: John
    email: johndoe@gmail.com
    courses: [
      "course_uuid_1",
      "course_uuid_2"
    ]
  }
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Nested projections should work. What result do you get?

Comment: And why are you using a native query?

Comment: @AlanHay 1. The result I have is that, the courses is null. 2. Since this is a native query. `SELECT *` wouldn't work without it.

Comment: BTW, this would work fine if I don't use `StudentProjection` and I just use `Student`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have try:

1. interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository, excerptProjection = projectionName.class
   To hard this projection to the repository.
2. Https:domain/contextpath/students/search/findAllByKeyword?projection=projectionName
   To apply projection for this rest api.
   And you need add more configuration as below:

   ```
    @Configuration
    public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {   

             config.getProjectionConfiguration().addProjection(projectionName.class));  

        }
    }
   ```

Comment: 1. I didn't get the `excerptProjection = projectionName.class` part. Could you provide a little more details ? 2. It is not an option, URL of the API shouldn't have to know about this projection. I would rather not use projection if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Data **nested closed projections** with **custom queries**, you need to make sure you are definitely:

1. Nesting projections
2. Explicitly declaring column aliases

I ran into the same issue, trying to figure out how to solve it. Your code would've worked totally fine if you just had done:

```
public interface StudentProjection {
    String getName();
    String getEmail();
    Set<CourseProjection> getCourses();
    
    interface CourseProjection {
        UUID getUuid();
    }
}
```

And then used your custom query like this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value = "SELECT s.name as name, s.email as email, c.uuid as uuid "
                    + "FROM student s "
                    + "LEFT JOIN courses c ON s.id = c.student_id "
                    + "WHERE s.name LIKE %str% OR c.student_id::text LIKE %str%")
Page<StudentProjection> findAllByKeyword(String keyword, Pageable pageable);
```

I also believe there was no need for using a native query, you could've just used `HQL/JPQL` instead or even Spring Data `query methods`.

I know this question is a bit old, but it can be helpful to other people out there.